# User Access Level Error 403 Although Accessed by Admin

Tags: yii

I wanted to make a user access level, but I have problem the admin (whose id_level = 1) still cannot access the specified page.
Here I have EWebUser.php

```
<?php
class EWebUser extends CWebUser{

protected $_model;

protected function loadUser()
{
    if ( $this->_model === null ) {
            $this->_model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id);
    }
    return $this->_model;
}

function getLevel()
{
    $user=$this->loadUser();
    if($user)
        return $user->id_level;
    return 100;
}
}
?>
```

Then here is the accessRules method in UserController.php

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        .......
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','admin','delete'),
            //'users'=>array('admin'),
            'expression'=>'$user->getLevel()<=1',
        ),
        .......
    );
}
```

I cannot access localhost/myappname/user.php, it throws error 403, although I logged in as Admin (id_level = 1).
I figured out `$this->_model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id);` , I made change `$this->id_user` because in my model the Primary key is `id_user` not `id` but it throws another error: Property "EWebUser.id_user" is not defined. Anyone can help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] by myself, I changed `$this->_id = $user->username;` to `$this->_id = $user->id_user;` in UserIdentity.php, there's no wrong codes on `$this->_model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id);` because the actual problem is in the UserIdentity